# Haskell Aeson: How to convert Value into custom type?

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

Can't find a good example. Appreciate any help. The JSON is as follows:

```
[{
  "EXIF:Make": "Canon",
  "EXIF:Model": "Canon PowerShot S95",
  "EXIF:Orientation": "Horizontal (normal)",
  "EXIF:XResolution": 180,
  "EXIF:YResolution": 180,
  "EXIF:ResolutionUnit": "inches"
}]
```

The code I used is as follows:

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Attoparsec
import Data.ByteString
x <- fmap (parse json) (Data.ByteString.readFile "json.txt")
```

How do I define & use the `FromJSON` type to convert from `x` into:

```
data Exif = Exif [[(String, String)]]
```

or similar data structure? Note the `[[]]` -- I'm expecting the JSON to have multiple top-level entries.

Answer (score 16):

Here's an idiomatic solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main
       where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Attoparsec

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.Text as T

data ExifEntry = ExifEntry { exifMake :: T.Text,
                             exifModel :: T.Text,
                             exifOrientation :: T.Text,
                             exifXResolution :: Int,
                             exifYResolution :: Int,
                             exifResolutionUnit :: T.Text
                           } deriving (Eq, Show)


instance FromJSON ExifEntry
  where
    parseJSON (Object v) = ExifEntry <$> 
                           v .: "EXIF:Make" <*>
                           v .: "EXIF:Model" <*>
                           v .: "EXIF:Orientation" <*>
                           v .: "EXIF:XResolution" <*>
                           v .: "EXIF:YResolution" <*>
                           v .: "EXIF:ResolutionUnit"
    parseJSON _          = mzero


parseAll :: B.ByteString -> [ExifEntry]
parseAll s = case (parse (fromJSON <$> json) s) of
  Done _ (Error err)  -> error err
  Done ss (Success e) -> e:(parseAll ss)
  _                   -> []

main :: IO ()
main = do s <- B.readFile "json.txt"
          let p = parseAll s
          print p
```

Testing:

```
$ cat json.txt 
{
  "EXIF:Make": "Canon",
  "EXIF:Model": "Canon PowerShot S95",
  "EXIF:Orientation": "Horizontal (normal)",
  "EXIF:XResolution": 180,
  "EXIF:YResolution": 180,
  "EXIF:ResolutionUnit": "inches"
}

{
  "EXIF:Make": "Canon",
  "EXIF:Model": "Canon PowerShot S995",
  "EXIF:Orientation": "Horizontal (normal)",
  "EXIF:XResolution": 180,
  "EXIF:YResolution": 180,
  "EXIF:ResolutionUnit": "inches"
}
$ ./dist/build/test/test
[ExifEntry {exifMake = "Canon", exifModel = "Canon PowerShot S95", exifOrientation = "Horizontal (normal)", exifXResolution = 180, exifYResolution = 180, exifResolutionUnit = "inches"},ExifEntry {exifMake = "Canon", exifModel = "Canon PowerShot S995", exifOrientation = "Horizontal (normal)", exifXResolution = 180, exifYResolution = 180, exifResolutionUnit = "inches"}]
```

Alternatively, here's a [slightly more ugly solution](https://gist.github.com/1063082) that gives you the data type you requested (`[[(Text,Text)]]`).