# Haskell, Aeson & JSON parsing into custom type

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

Following on from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566149/haskell-aeson-how-to-convert-value-into-custom-type), I've found I'm totally stuck. I'm trying to parse a JSON structure into my own type, and not only am I stuck on how to parse the Array, I'm not even sure if I'm using the Aeson library as intended. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code:

```
data Exif = Exif [(T.Text, ExifValue)] deriving (Show)
data ExifValue = 
    ExifText T.Text | 
    ExifInt Integer | 
    ExifDouble Double | 
    ExifBool Bool | 
    ExifArray [ExifValue] 
    deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON ExifValue where
    parseJSON (Number (I n)) = return $ ExifInt n
    parseJSON (Number (D n)) = return $ ExifDouble n
    parseJSON (String s)     = return $ ExifText s
    parseJSON (Bool b)       = return $ ExifBool b
    -- parseJSON (Array a)      = ?????

instance FromJSON Exif where
    parseJSON (Object o) = do
        x <- sequence $ map f (M.assocs o)
        return $ Exif x
        where 
        f (t, x) = do
            y <- parseJSON x 
            return ((t, y) :: (T.Text, ExifValue))

parseExifFile = fmap parseExifData . B.readFile

parseExifData :: B.ByteString -> Data.Attoparsec.Result (Data.Aeson.Result [Exif])
parseExifData content = parse (fmap fromJSON json) content
```

The test file:

```
[{
  "SourceFile": "test.jpg",
  "ExifTool:ExifToolVersion": 8.61,
  "File:FileName": "test.jpg",
  "File:FileSize": 2174179,
  "File:FileModifyDate": "2011:07:27 16:53:49-07:00",
  "File:FilePermissions": 644,
  "File:FileType": "JPEG",
  "File:MIMEType": "image/jpeg",
  "File:ExifByteOrder": "MM",
  "File:CurrentIPTCDigest": "32d6a77098a73aa816f2570c9472735a",
  "File:ImageWidth": 2592,
  "File:ImageHeight": 1936,
  "File:EncodingProcess": 0,
  "File:BitsPerSample": 8,
  "File:ColorComponents": 3,
  "File:YCbCrSubSampling": "2 2",
  "XMP:Subject": ["alpha","beta","gamma"]
}]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to follow the type of `parseJSON` a little bit down a rabbit trail, but once you recognize what `(Array a)` represents, it should be straightforward.

`parseJSON` has type `Value -> Parser a`, so `(Array a)` has type `Value`. One of the variants in the `Value` type is `Array Array`, so the `a` in `(Array a)` must be of the type `Array`, which is defined as `Vector Value`. The `Value`s inside that `Vector` are what you want to call `parseJSON` on to return your list, so check out what you can do with a [`Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/latest/doc/html/Data-Vector.html#t:Vector).

The easiest approach would probably to convert `a` to a list with `Vector.toList`, and then use `mapM` to parse the `Values`.

Alternately, you could avoid the `Vector` to list conversion by changing your `ExifArray` variant to hold `Vector ExifValue`, and then using `Vector.mapM`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not native english speaker, so i may not understand you very well. I guess you want to know how to parse json into recursive data type like `ExifValue` you presented.
So i made a simple example to show how to parse json into recursive data type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Attoparsec
import Data.Attoparsec.Number
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Vector as V

data Data = D1 Int | D2 [Data]
    deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON Data where
    parseJSON (Number (I n)) = return $ D1 $ fromInteger n
    parseJSON (Array a)    = D2 <$> mapM parseJSON (V.toList a)

main = do
    let v = fromJust $ maybeResult $ parse json "[1,2,3,[5,3,[6,3,5]]]"
    let v1 :: Data
        v1 = case fromJSON v of
                 Success a -> a
                 Error s   -> error s
    print v1
```

Answer (score 3):

A slightly newer build of the [aeson library (0.3.2.12)](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/0.3.2.12/doc/html/Data-Aeson-TH.html) supports autogenerating JSON instances.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.TH (deriveJSON)
import Data.Attoparsec
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.Text as T

data Exif = Exif [(T.Text, ExifValue)] deriving (Show)
data ExifValue = 
    ExifText T.Text | 
    ExifInt Integer | 
    ExifDouble Double | 
    ExifBool Bool | 
    ExifArray [ExifValue] 
    deriving (Show)

deriveJSON id ''Exif
deriveJSON id ''ExifValue

parseExifFile = fmap parseExifData . B.readFile

parseExifData :: B.ByteString -> Data.Attoparsec.Result (Data.Aeson.Result [Exif])
parseExifData content = parse (fmap fromJSON json) content
```

Produces:

```
instance ToJSON Exif where
  { toJSON
      = \ value_a1Va
          -> case value_a1Va of { Exif arg1_a1Vb -> toJSON arg1_a1Vb } }
instance FromJSON Exif where
  { parseJSON
      = \ value_a1Vc
          -> case value_a1Vc of {
               arg_a1Vd -> (Exif Data.Functor.<$> parseJSON arg_a1Vd) } }

instance ToJSON ExifValue where
  { toJSON
      = \ value_a1Wd
          -> case value_a1Wd of {
               ExifText arg1_a1We
                 -> object [(T.pack "ExifText" .= toJSON arg1_a1We)]
               ExifInt arg1_a1Wf
                 -> object [(T.pack "ExifInt" .= toJSON arg1_a1Wf)]
               ExifDouble arg1_a1Wg
                 -> object [(T.pack "ExifDouble" .= toJSON arg1_a1Wg)]
               ExifBool arg1_a1Wh
                 -> object [(T.pack "ExifBool" .= toJSON arg1_a1Wh)]
               ExifArray arg1_a1Wi
                 -> object [(T.pack "ExifArray" .= toJSON arg1_a1Wi)] } }
instance FromJSON ExifValue where
  { parseJSON
      = \ value_a1Wj
          -> case value_a1Wj of {
               Object obj_a1Wk
                 -> case Data.Map.toList obj_a1Wk of {
                      [(conKey_a1Wl, conVal_a1Wm)]
                        -> case conKey_a1Wl of {
                             _ | (conKey_a1Wl == T.pack "ExifText")
                               -> case conVal_a1Wm of {
                                    arg_a1Wn
                                      -> (ExifText Data.Functor.<$> parseJSON arg_a1Wn) }
                               | (conKey_a1Wl == T.pack "ExifInt")
                               -> case conVal_a1Wm of {
                                    arg_a1Wo
                                      -> (ExifInt Data.Functor.<$> parseJSON arg_a1Wo) }
                               | (conKey_a1Wl == T.pack "ExifDouble")
                               -> case conVal_a1Wm of {
                                    arg_a1Wp
                                      -> (ExifDouble Data.Functor.<$> parseJSON arg_a1Wp) }
                               | (conKey_a1Wl == T.pack "ExifBool")
                               -> case conVal_a1Wm of {
                                    arg_a1Wq
                                      -> (ExifBool Data.Functor.<$> parseJSON arg_a1Wq) }
                               | (conKey_a1Wl == T.pack "ExifArray")
                               -> case conVal_a1Wm of {
                                    arg_a1Wr
                                      -> (ExifArray Data.Functor.<$> parseJSON arg_a1Wr) }
                               | otherwise -> Control.Monad.mzero }
                      _ -> Control.Monad.mzero }
               _ -> Control.Monad.mzero } }
```